# WP and Node implementations of Phpass does not match when there are international characters in the password

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, phpass

I want to authenticate WP users using my own authentication service written in Node. I have users saved in the `wp_users` table. Their passwords are hashed using Phpass method by WordPress. When a user is trying to log into his account, WP is using `CheckPassword()` method and returns boolean `true`/`false` if the password matches or not.

Now I want to use Node to compare user password to the WP hash. I found [node-phpass module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phpass) on NPM, which is supposed to provide the Phpass algorithm for password hashing.

It's all fine until I use international characters. Here's an example:

In WP, I set the password like this, and get a hash:

P: `alamakota`
H: `$P$BSrncAWIY2KU7waUGLzayaon6v3gKU1`

When I try to log in, WP says *"All fine, come in, man"*

Now, I take the hash and try to validate it using node-phpass module:

```
const hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true, 7);
const valid = hasher.CheckPassword('alamakota', '$P$BSrncAWIY2KU7waUGLzayaon6v3gKU1');
console.log(valid); // => true
```

and it says *"Cool, password match!"*

It works perfectly in the other way also.

**Now, where does the problem occur, you may ask? Here:**

The situation is *almost* exactly the same as before, but I will put `ą` character in the password and hash it using WP:

P: `alamakotą`
H: `$P$B6kY.rneyNwdPvAgd0lDq6oYv82XOd1`

Again, when validated using WP, it says *"Password match! Come in."*

Unfortunately, when I try to compare the password using node-phpass, it says *"Sorry, man, you shall not pass"*:

```
const hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true, 7);
const valid = hasher.CheckPassword('alamakotą', '$P$B6kY.rneyNwdPvAgd0lDq6oYv82XOd1');
console.log(valid); // => false
```

It also doesn't work in the other way.

Why is it so? Why can I not use WP hash in the Node.js when there are international characters in the password?

**UPDATE:**

I've just found that PHP's `md5()` function and JS'es `crypto.createHash('md5')` does not return the same hash when there are international characters in the input string. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that the PHP's `md5()` function returns different hash than JS'es `crypto.createHash('md5')` because of character encoding. I've used [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) before comparing the password against the hash and everything works as expected:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8');
const hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true, 7);
const valid = hasher.CheckPassword(utf8.encode('alamakotą'), '$P$B6kY.rneyNwdPvAgd0lDq6oYv82XOd1');
console.log(valid); // => true
```